# How to trade European style option on Fidelity?

Tags: options, fidelity

My goal is to sell European-style put options on TLT. How can I go about doing that on the Fidelity platform? So far I have been able to find an index that tracks atm putwrite strategy - [PTLT index](https://www.cboe.com/us/indices/dashboard/PTLT/) but how can I go about trading options on that? What ticker symbol I need to use? I fully understand that it is not the index you trade, you always trade an equity or ETF (and options tied to them). Does that mean I need to find an ETF that tracks that index? (much like TLTW)

Comment: Is there a reason you specifically want European options? Or do you just want options on that ETF? Note that options on major indexes do exist - they are just cash settled (i.e. you don't "buy" the index at expiry).

Comment: @DStanley- I want to eliminate the risk of early assignments. This is especially important for underlying paying dividends.

Comment: Early assignment is only a risk with very little time remaining on an option with very little time value, and you can avoid the risk by closing out the option a day or two early.  That said, I don't see any options on that index, american or european.

Comment: According to a quick Bloomberg check, all TLT options that are publicly traded are American style. Insofar, you would need to buy an OTC option. Finding an ETF that tracks a somewhat "esoteric" Index that computes a hypothetical strategy (PTLT) and has listed options is a bit far stretched.